# "'SpaceShip' does not name a type" even though SpaceShip certainly is a type

Tags: c++, class, types, composition

I'm working on an Asteroids game as a way to teach myself some programming stuff, and I'm getting this error that one of my classes doesn't name a type.

I have a SpaceShip class that inherits from Entity class (both are defined) and I have a Bullet class that inherits from Entity. I'm trying to put a SpaceShip Member into the Bullet Class as a way of telling who shot the bullet, but it keeps telling me that "'SpaceShip' does not name a type".

Here's some code:

spaceship.h

```
class SpaceShip : public Entity
{
private:
    int lives;
    int score;
    int animationRow;
    int shotsFired;

public:
SpaceShip();
void Init(SDL_Surface *image = NULL);

void Destroy();
void Update();
void Render( SDL_Surface *screen );
...
};
```

bullet.h

```
#ifndef BULLET_H
#define BULLET_H


#include <SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>

#include "entity.h"
#include "spaceship.h"
#include "Globals.h"


class Bullet : public Entity
{
private:
    SpaceShip* owner;

public:
    Bullet( SpaceShip* ship );

    void Update();
    void Render( SDL_Surface *screen );
    void Destroy();

    void Collided(int objectID);

};

#endif // BULLET_H
```

Why isn't it finding the SpaceShip type?

Comment: Present [your minimal testcase](http://sscce.org). Y'know, the one you've been debugging with today so far.

Comment: Does `spaceship.h` possibly include anything?

Comment: `spaceship.h` includes `entity.h` and `bullet.h` because the ship fires a bullet

Comment: @Goldentoa11 Circular dependency problem then, `spaceship.h` needs to know first about `bullet.h` which needs to know first about `spaceship.h` which...

Comment: okay. So I fixed my problem by by changing `bullet = ship->fireBullet();` to `bullet = new Bullet(ship);` with the appropriate changes to the class files. But isn't there a better way to do that? I want to keep the bullet creation in the ship class because it seems appropriate that the ship would create the bullet.

Comment: @Goldentoa11 Prefer forward declarations to includes in your include files, and move the actual `#include` to your cpp file if possible.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Like I said, I'm trying to learn from this (read: I'm a total noob to this), so could you explain what you mean by that last comment? I'm not following...

Comment: @Goldentoa11 For your example above, simply remove `#include "spaceship.h"` and replace it by `class SpaceShip;`. No more circular dependency. If, in bullet.cpp, you actually need to know how SpaceShip is defined, include spaceship.h there instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems (based on clarification in comments) that your code has [Circular dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). `SpaceShip` depends on `Bullet` which in turn depends back on `SpaceShip`. You need to re-factor your code to remove circular dependencies.

Usually this can be accomplished easily with [Forward decleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) but more advanced methods (more OOP correct) include [interfaces](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm), [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) or better yet events (signals)